# wordpress functions, PHP not processing, showing as plain text

Tags: php, wordpress

```
     <?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

printf( __( 'Username: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_login ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User email: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_email ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User first name: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_firstname ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User last name: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_lastname ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User display name: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->display_name ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User ID: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->ID ) );
```

I am ultimately trying to do more than the above, but for now I am just trying to start simple since I was having trouble.

I am unable to get this to display processed; it shows as plain text when placed in a code or text module using divi builder or even in the text view of the basic wordpress page editor.

So in the end, I will have custom fields in the user meta table that i will need to print to screen in emails to send to users as well as in a table on my website.

Thank you in advance!

I've seen things like php anywhere plugins but that seems unsafe. Also have seen php shortcode managers, but im not sure i want to go that route or if that would work when building tables.

Comment: Please use "wp_get_current_user()"  function as 
 "get_currentuserinfo()" function is deprected  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/

Comment: So where are you adding this php-code exactly? (I believe with divi the common thing is to have a child-theme and just stuff your custom code into functions.php.) If your php is not processed in your html/php files that's a web server problem, but if you are trying to add this to some block in the builder then I wouldn't expect it to work. You could create a shortcode in your functions.php and then use that from the builder.

Comment: On a page so far to test things. Created new page, pasted code into text box, code box, and also plain wordpress text editor tab. Doesn't process the code.

Comment: Yup, that won't work unless you add some of those hideous run-anywhere plugins or similar. If it's code for a specific page I would create a new `page-{id or slug}.php`. ie: `page-fun.php` by copying the exising page.php. And add your code there. If it's more general code I'd use functions.php. Make sure you have direct access to the files or you can lock yourself out if you mess up your code.

Comment: The other option to run code from text-boxes is shortcodes. But you still need to add your shortcode-code to functions.php and then use the shortcode to call it from your content. It would be too easy to break any wordpress site if you could just run arbitrary php from text-boxes. Even without assuming the average wordpress user knows no php.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.

Let me explain what I am trying to do, as maybe you have better ways to go about it then I can think of. I am trying to display a table with columns for users showing licenses and license numbers and credits required to fulfill a license. These would be things stored in custom fields and custom posts, could be called possibly through a wordpress function or sql query, and some columns would be based on calculations of other fields.

I thought using html to create a table and html to create an email would be a way to go about doing this.

Comment: @ippi s answer is correct. Create a custom shortcode in your functions.php, call the shortcode inside your page editor. WordPress tinymce editor does not allow php code.